# How to implement bootstrap-datepicker sandbox in HTML example

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I found out the datepicker for bootstrap at the link below, well, i downloaded the development version, and then after configuring some settings at the page in there, and after attaching the required stylesheets and javascript files, still i can't get an HTML example working.

This is the [link](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=1&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=true&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&calendarWeeks=on&autoclose=on&todayHighlight=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) for the example to download.

I gathered the required CSS and JS as below:

```
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="build/build_standalone.less.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

HTML as below:

```
    <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
    </div>
```

The JS script at the end of the file as below:

```
    <script>

      $('#sandbox-container .input-daterange').datepicker({
         startDate: "-12/30/2014",
         endDate: "+01/15/2015",
         startView: 1,
         clearBtn: true,
         calendarWeeks: true,
         autoclose: true,
         todayHighlight: true
       });
  </script>
```

Now the two inputs appear but they don't work, I don't know whats missing. I also can't find any HTML examples in the downloaded files for the demo, it's all .md, .jason, and other formats that it seems to be raw and I don't know actually how to implement this simply in HTML file.

Comment: You are applying the event to div not for each input. You need to specify for each (start and end)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see `#sandbox-container` in your HTML:

```
<div id="sandbox-container">        
    <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mojito, if the above answer solved your problem or helped you find the cause of your issue you should mark it as "Accepted" answer. If you don't, even though you asked this question first, we won't be able to set the duplicates as duplicates of yours, as it doesn't have an accepted answers, so, even though older, yours will be marked as duplicate. It's up to you.