# how to use bootstrap-datepicker sandbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

i'm using angular 4, i want to use bootstrap-datepicker sandbox,
heres the code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/libs/datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/libs/datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Main jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="./assets/libs/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"> </script>

  <div class="input-group date">
   <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
  </div>
```

component.ts :

```
 $('#sandbox-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
startDate: "-12/30/2014",
endDate: "+01/15/2015",
startView: 1,
clearBtn: true,
calendarWeeks: true,
autoclose: true,
todayHighlight: true
});
```

but when i click this the input text field, the datepicker doesnt appears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement bootstrap-datepicker sandbox in HTML example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684385/how-to-implement-bootstrap-datepicker-sandbox-in-html-example)

Comment: anny errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#sandbox-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
  startDate: "-12/30/2014",
  endDate: "+01/15/2015",
  startView: 1,
  clearBtn: true,
  calendarWeeks: true,
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.css">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Main jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js">
</script>

<div id="sandbox-container">
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the selector `#sandbox-container`, you have to put the calendar input into it or remove that selector.

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: thanks for enswer but i tried that, the same problem

Comment: I can't see what other problem you're facing.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you https://jsfiddle.net/m6Ls4w4w/

```js
$('.date').datepicker({
  startDate: "-12/30/2014",
  endDate: "+01/15/2015",
  startView: 1,
  clearBtn: true,
  calendarWeeks: true,
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<div class="input-group date">
   <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

You are giving wrong selector.

Comment: thanks for enswer but i tried that, the same problem